# Select ID That has multiple attributes and values

Tags: mysql

i have table1 :

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name3 |
|  4 | name4 |
+----+-------+
```

i have table2 :

+------+---------+----------+
| id   | attribut|    value |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1    |    1    |      1   |
| 1    |    3    |      3   |
| 2    |    1    |      1   |
| 2    |    3    |      4   |
+------+---------+--------- +

i want to select the distinct id(s) and name(s) in table1 that have ( attribut 1 and value 1)  and (attribut 3 and value 3) in table 2

the result will be 1/name1 in this case

thanks for help !!

Comment: Do you have a query started? Preferably one with a join of the two tables.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
  where id in(select id
                from table2
               where (attribut, value) in ( (1,1), (3,3) )
               group by id
              having count(*)=2
             )
```